# IIS Web Server file change monitoring tools?

Tags: iis, web-server, monitoring, files

We are looking for a tool to run in the background of out Server 2008 R2 IIS web-server.

We want a tool that can tell us when new files re created, or changes are made to existing file to watch for malicious code. E.G. new PHP files being create or modified when they shouldn't be.

Any suggestions?

Something that has some notifications or reporting would be helpful as well.

Comment: I should also note it would be ideal that if there is a server portion of the software, that it could run on Server 2008 R2 as well.

Answer (score 1):

I found that using System.IO.FileSystemWatcher in a Powershell script to write file folder changes events to a log file, and then having Task Scheduler sent me that file via email as an attachement daily does the job well.

See: http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Powershell-FileSystemWatche-dfd7084b